# Building wheels with travis' pypi deploy

Tags: travis-ci, pypi

I tried out the travis-ci pypi deployment, as can be seen here:

https://travis-ci.org/Simplistix/testfixtures/jobs/80429422

The pertinent .travis.yaml bits are:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: ...
  password:
    secure: ...
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: Simplistix/testfixtures
```

...but this has only created an sdist.

How can I configure it to also create and upload a wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in deploy section parameter "distributions", for example:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  distributions: "sdist bdist bdist_wheel"
  ... e.t.c
```

Comment: This [doesn't appear to be working for me](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba/issues/71#issuecomment-238057243).